# Creating New columns via dictionary pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with 2 columns

```
combined | out_dict
--------------------
"sentence 1" | {class1: 30, class2: 42, class3: 5, class4:42}
"sentence 2" | {class1: 60, class2: 10, class3: 40, class4:40}
```

Now I want to convert it to a new dataframe as follows. If probability is greater or equal to 40, then make 2 new columns for it. i.e

```
combined      | class1 | class1_score | class2 | class2_score | class3 | class3_score |class4 | class4_score
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"sentence 1" | Nan       |  NaN       | 1     |   42          | Nan    | Nan          | 1     | 42

"sentence 2" | 1       |  60       | Nan     |   Nan          | 1    | 40          | 1     | 40
```

I have tried using some manual logic, like looping over the whole dataframe, but that seems much inefficient. Kindly guide me in creating an optimal solution for this.

###### Edit

My solution:

```
self.df[list(ref_garm_dict.keys())] = "" # a dictionary with classes name
    for _, row in self.df.iterrows():
        for key, value in row["out_dict"].items():
            if value >= 40:
                row[key] = 1
                row[key + "_score"] = value # has no effect so _score columns are not created.
```

Comment: Share your tried, maybe they could be improved

Comment: Your dicts are confusing. Are they strings? Or are they actual dicts? Try `print(type(df['out_dict'].iloc[0]))`

Comment: Yes they are actual dictionaries.

Comment: @azro I have added

Answer (score 0):

You may first convert all dictionaries into columns as is

```
df = df.set_index('combined')['out_dict'].apply(pd.Series)
```

Then add/modify column as you need

```
for col in df.columns:
    score_name = f'{col}_score'
    df[score_name] = df[col]
    df[score_name].loc[df[col]<40] = np.nan
    df[col] = df[score_name].isna().map({False: 1})
```

Lastly to take care of the formatting.

```
df.sort_index(axis=1).reset_index()
```